# $lookup in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I have the following collections in **db** database:

**user**: it contains documents in the following format:

```
const data1 ={
            username:req.body.username,
            email:req.body.email,
            role:req.body.role
 
        }
    db1.collection('user').insertOne(data1, function(err,res){
        if(err) throw err;
        
        console.log(res.insertedId)
        objectId = res.insertedId;
```

**password**: it contains documents in the following format:

```
db3.collection('password').insertMany([
            {
                userid:objectId,
                password:req.body.password
            },
           
        ])
```

how can i access email and password for user login the front end is react js

user object_id is the userid of the password , how can solve $lookup (aggregation) in mongo db

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

A simple $lookup would look like this:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/USKiiSfn9iT

```
db.user.aggregate([
  { $match: { username: "Person1" } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "password",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "userid",
      as: "password"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      email: 1,
      role: 1,
      username: 1,
      password: { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$password.password", 0 ] }
    }
  }
])
```

As React is a frontend tool, you will need some mechanism of accessing the db through a server side / secure and authentication manner. I believe that this is out of scope of the question and topic though as there will be a myriad of opinions and there are many articles already present that will allow you to do this.

Example setup: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-passport-local-passport-js-strategy-633bbab6195